# cannot open fortran module in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, fortran

I am wring Fortran code in linux. My module file is in a *.f90 file. 
"program main" is in another *.f90 file. When I tried to compile my code in ubuntu "gfortran main.f90", errors said that can't find my module file.

```
program main
use module_name
```

Just now, I see someone say the files are compiled alphabetically. If this is the reason, then I am in big trouble. Because my program has called many subroutines and functions which are in different f90 files. So how to resolve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: *I see someone say the files are compiled alphabetically*  -- that's nonsense, don't believe it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have a file containing the main program `main.f90` and another file containing the module `mod.f90`. The correct way to compile and generate an executable named `main` will be

```
gfortran mod.f90 main.f90 -o main
```

You have not specified the module file while compiling therefore it is unable to compile

Answer (score 0):

Along with including the file name, use the specifier -I in gfortran to tell the compiler where to look for the file in case it can't find it.
ex:
        `gfortran -I/path/to/module`